# Difference between `cargo build` , `cargo build-bpf` and `cargo build-sbf`

Tags: rust-cargo, solana, anchor-solana, solana-cli

I am new to blockchain and I am using solana/anchor/cargo/rust to build a project. I am confused about these commands. What is the difference between `cargo build`, `cargo build-bpf` and `cargo build-sbf`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`cargo build` - Unless otherwise directed to build for a different architecture, this will compile your rust source and emit an executable file.

`cargo build-bpf` - Solana programs (smart contracts) are compiled to BPF (google it) bytecode. The Solana program run-time executes your smart contract in a BPF VM. deprecated in favor of:

`cargo build-sbf` - More comprehensive implementation of generated byte-code and interpreter

Comment: Is there a reference in the Solana GitHub repo for the difference between `cargo build-bpf` and `cargo build-sbf`? More comprehensive implementation is a bit ambiguous.